# Создать функцию, которая принимает массив чисел и возвращает разницу между наибольшим и наименьшим числом в массиве

Tags: javascript, функции

**Помогите пожалуйста, написать js код.**

Описание:
Допиши функцию getDifference, которая принимает массив чисел numbers и возвращает разницу между наибольшим и наименьшим числом в массиве.



Пример:
[42, 45, 1, 78, 92, 10] нужно вернуть 91


Ёщо пример:

```
getDifference([42, 45, 1, 78, 92, 10]) === 91 (92 - 1)
getDifference([42]) === 0
getDifference([42, 42, 42]) === 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const getDifference = arr => Math.max(...arr) - Math.min(...arr)
 
console.log(getDifference([42, 45, 1, 78, 92, 10]));
```

Comment: Два прохода по массиву. Можно сделать за один.

Comment: @Эникейщик, сложность такая же; а что быстрее, так не угадать: проход нативный, но `...arr` может что-то аллоцировать